# Looping through txt file in VBScript to test file

Tags: vbscript

Updating a script for efficiency. A JAL Script calls the VBScript in a loop to check each file in a txt file.

What I need help on is to take the file name, add the FormattedDT (date/time) to it (original file name is FullFileName), then copy it over to an archive folder (\a70tsgnaeasa001\eas\server\log\archive). For example if the file name from the txt file it is reading from is \A70TSGNAEASA001\d$\EAS\Server\FIPS\BCBSFIPS.TXT and it was last modified 10/27/2017 at 3:00, then I would want the destination to be \a70tsgnaeasa001\eas\server\log\archive\BCBSFIPS_10_27_2017_03_00_00.TXT

I am having trouble figuring out how to remove the .extension, appending the date/time of the file, and then copying it to the archive folder. I put the code I have so far below.

TIA

**TXT File Format**

```
REM there is a comment here on the first line
\\filepath1
\\filepath2
...
\\filepathN
```

**VBScript:**

```
option explicit

Dim SFSO, WSSL, FullFileName, txtFile, exitCode, txtLine, ArchiveFolder, 
CopyFileName
Dim ArchDT, FormattedDT, mon, day, yr, hr, min, sec, empty
Set ArchiveFolder, "\\\\A70TSGNAEASA001\\eas\\Server\\log\\Archive\\"

Set SFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WSSL = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

exitCode = 0

'tests for no args
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 then
    WScript.quit (9999)
End If

txtFile = WScript.Arguments(0)

Set f = SFSO.OpenTextFile(txtFile)
On Error Resume Next
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream

txtLine = f.ReadLine
If(Left(txtLine,2) == "\\")
    FullFileName = txtLine

    ' Check for file exists  
    If SFSO.fileexists(FullFileName) then 
        ' Check file status
        If VarType(SFSO.OpenTextFile(FullFileName,8,False)) = vbError Then      
            exitCode = 9999
        Else
        ' create archive folder path

        'get modified date time, format to _mm_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss
         ArchDT = CDate(SFSO.DateLastModified(FullFileName))
             mon = Month(ArchDT)
             day = Day(ArchDT)
             yr = Year(ArchDT)
             hr = Hour(ArchDT)
             min = Minute(ArchDT)
             sec = Second(ArchDT)
         FormattedDT = "_"&mon&"_"&day&"_"&yr&"_"&hr&"_"&min&"_"&sec

        ' File name with date/time appended to it
            'Part I'm having trouble with

        'copy file to archive folder (how I would copy the file)
        ' SFSO.CopyFile(FullFileName, CopyFileName)
        End If
    Else
        exitCode = 9999
    End If
End If
Loop

f.Close
Err.Clear
SFSO.Close
WScript.quit(exitCode)
```

Comment: SO is not a place where you post your requirements and other people rewrite your code for you. What have you tried so far to make it work? What didn't work the way you expected? If you're unfamiliar with file handling in VBScript please visit the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx) first.

Comment: Ok I understand, I will update code to show what I have, I thought I will show the original first to prevent any confusions.

Comment: Really the only thing I was planning to do, is to change where it sets FullFileName = WScript.Arguments(0) to a new variable, where arg(0) is now the text file it was originally reading from. Then I added a do until loop that sets FullFileName = f.ReadLine, and left everything else pretty much the same. Would that be how you would do it?

Comment: Probably. The condition where you check if the line begins with a double backslash is incorrect, though. Looks like a mixture of VBScript and JavaScript. Change it to `If Left(txtLine, 2) = "\\" Then`. Or you could remove the condition and just [skip over the first line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhhkawe.aspx) before going into the loop if you're certain that there will always be a comment in the first line.

Comment: Sorry for the silly questions, I'm quite the beginner when it comes to VBScripting. I think I have figured out most of the stuff that I needed to do with the help of Google! Just a little more left, updated the script I have now, and what I need help with clear instructions. Thanks! @AnsgarWiechers